# Error:Unresolvable dependency resolving $resource in clas JsonResource in file Container.php

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, laravel-7

I am strugling with this problem for hours.
The problem appear from Laravel when I am trying make a POST API call. I have to mention that GET call is working fine.

The error is this:
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: **Unresolvable dependency resolving** [Parameter #0 [ <required> **$resource** ]] in class Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource in file C:\laragon\www\smart-life-style\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1032

This is my laravel code:

api.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('register', 'UserController@register')->name('register');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('details', 'UserController@details');
    Route::apiResource('schedule', 'ScheduleController');
});
```

ScheduleController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Schedules;
use App\Http\Resources\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ScheduleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        return Schedule::collection(Schedules::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(){
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Schedule $request)
    {
        $schedule = new Schedules();

        if (isset($request['title'])) {
            $schedule->title = $request['title'];
        };

        if (isset($request['start'])) {
            $schedule->start = $request['start'];
        };

        if (isset($request['end'])) {
            $schedule->end = $request['end'];
        };

        if ($schedule->save()) {
            return response()->json(new Schedule($schedule), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t save schedule', 500);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Schedule $id)
    {
        return response()->json(new Schedule(Schedules::find($id)), 200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Schedule $schedule)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Schedule $id)
    {
        if (Schedules::find($id)->delete()) {
            return response()->json('Success on delete carpet', 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t delete carpet', 500);
        }
    }

    public function creazaProgramare(Schedule $request)
    {
        $schedule = new Schedules();

        if (isset($request['title'])) {
            $schedule->title = $request['title'];
        };

        if (isset($request['start'])) {
            $schedule->start = $request['start'];
        };

        if (isset($request['end'])) {
            $schedule->end = $request['end'];
        };

        if ($schedule->save()) {
            return response()->json(new Schedule($schedule), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json('Error can\'t save schedule', 500);
        };
    }

}
```

ScheduleResource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Schedule extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
                'title' => $this->title,
                'start' => $this->start,
                'end' => $this->end
        ];
    }
}
```

Schedule Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedules extends Model
{
    //
}
```

I tried to run "composer install" and nothing happened.

Laravel version: 7.30.4
PHP: 7.2.19 (cli)

Should be there any difference if in postman at body I use  "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem due to another post.

The problem was that in ScheduleController I was calling $request with different type than it should.

Change: public function store(Schedule $request)

Into:   public function store(**Request** $request)

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this command

php artisan optimize:clear

Answer (score -1):

u must change this:
return response()->json(new Schedule($schedule), 200);
on:
return response()->json(new Schedule(['resource' => $schedule]), 200);